# SSIS Extra quotes added in my Execute sql task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a global string variable that stores a table name and I would like to use this variable inside of a Execute SQL Task when I'm writing a query.

The query I have in the Execute SQL Task is: `CREATE TABLE ?`

This is supposed to create a table inside the Netezza system which is where my OLEDB is connected to. (The connection is successful)

The problem that I'm getting when I look at the output is: `ERROR: 'CREATE TABLE 'TableName''` Expecting an identifier found a "keyword".

As you can see, it adds quotations around my table name which is stored in a variable. Inside the parameter mapping I add my variable with direction =>input, data type => nvarchar, parameter name=> 0 and parameter size => 0. How can I access the value of the variable without the quotations?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` does not accept parameters, so you can't actually pass the table name as one. A naive replacement of the name as if it were a parameter won't have the desired effect, as you've established. You'll need to construct the whole SQL command in a variable, and pass the contents as the command itself. (Off the top of my head, I can't remember the most convenient way to do this in SSIS; a script task can certainly do it, but that may be overkill.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` is like a variable in SQL Server. You can't do syntax like the following in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Table sysname = N'YourTable';
SELECT *
FROM @Table;
```

You need to create a second variable in your SSIS package, and set the expression to be:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + {Your Variable} + "..."
```

*(Obviously replace `{Your Variable}` with your variable's full name. For example `@[User::TableName]`)*

You'll then need to change the value of SQLSourceType to Variable and select your **new** variable in the SourceVariable dropdown.

Comment: I tried this.  I have two variables, one that stores the table name and the other that stores the query. But I get the error: `Executing SQL Task: Executing the query ""Create table" + @[User::tableName]" Syntax Error or access violation`

Comment: That error suggests you've put the expression in the SQL Statement value. let me be a bit more specific.

Comment: Note that, even though the question is tagged `sql-server`, it's actually about creating a table in Netezza through OLE DB, and parameter passing is apparently implemented by textual replacement in this driver. In SQL Server, this would still fail, but the error should be different (because it would properly parameterize the statement, yet parameterization would still not be allowed). Minor detail and the same solution, of course.

Comment: My mistake was I didn't create the variable using the expression like you told me to rather I manually wrote it out in the Value column